# urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=51336) error while testing herokuapp using selenium python

Tags: python, automated-tests, python-unittest

i am writing test automation code for https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/ using python unittest and selenium, also pom and singleton patterns. i encounter problem while launching multiple tests multiple tests, they pass separately or when i launch tests class without teardown function but when i launch test class second tests fails with error :

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 198, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 793, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 496, in _make_request
    conn.request(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 400, in request
    self.endheaders()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Lib\http\client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Lib\http\client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Lib\http\client.py", line 979, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 238, in connect
    self.sock = self._new_conn()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 213, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021EEBE49710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\Tests\exit_intent.py", line 52, in test_02_exit_intent_dismiss
    exit_intent_steps.exit_intent()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\allure_commons\_allure.py", line 192, in impl
    return func(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\Steps\exit_intent_steps.py", line 23, in exit_intent
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 407, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 302, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 322, in _request
    response = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 144, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 279, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 444, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 877, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 877, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 877, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 847, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tornikes Davaleba\herokuapp-test\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=51336): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/030bc8e6a752996d7f5d5bceb11f9d06/execute/sync (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021EEBE49710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

here is singleton class :

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from loguru import logger

class SingletonClass:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
            cls._instance.driver = None
        return cls._instance

    def get_driver(self):
        if self.driver is None:
            c_options = Options()
            c_options.add_argument("--enable-automation")
            c_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=c_options)
            self.driver.maximize_window()
        return self.driver

    def quit_driver(self):
        if self.driver is not None:
            self.driver.quit()
            self.driver = None
            time.sleep(5)

    def find_element(self, by, value: str, timeout=100):
        driver = self.get_driver()
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((by, value)))
            return element
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    def navigate_to(self, url):
        driver = self.get_driver()
        driver.get(url)

    def wait_for_element_clickable(self, by, value: str, timeout=10):
        driver = self.get_driver()
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, value)))
            return element
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    def click_element(self, by, value: str, timeout=10):
        element = self.wait_for_element_clickable(by, value, timeout)
        element.click()

    def input_text(self, by, value: str, text, timeout=10):
        element = self.wait_for_element_clickable(by, value, timeout)
        element.send_keys(text)

    def switch_to_frame(self, by, value: str, timeout=10):
        driver = self.get_driver()
        try:
            frame = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
                EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((by, value)))
            return frame
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    def switch_to_default_content(self):
        self.get_driver().switch_to.default_content()

    def get_current_url(self):
        return self.get_driver().current_url
```

and here is test class :

```
import os
import sys
import unittest

import allure
from loguru import logger

parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)

from Steps.base_page_steps import BasePageSteps
from Pages.exit_intent import ExitIntentPage
from Steps.exit_intent_steps import ExitIntent
from Utils.singleton_class import SingletonClass

singleton = SingletonClass()
base_steps = BasePageSteps()
exit_intent_page = ExitIntentPage()
exit_intent_steps = ExitIntent()


class TestExitIntentPage(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        logger.info(f"Start new test")
        singleton.navigate_to("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/")

    def tearDown(self):
        logger.info("before" + str(singleton.driver is None))
        singleton.quit_driver()
        logger.info("after" + str(singleton.driver is None))

    @allure.suite("Exit intent")
    @allure.title("Modal window")
    @allure.description("checking that after leaving viewpoint pane modal window appears")
    def test_01_trigger_intent(self):
        base_steps.open_exit_intent()
        print("Running test_trigger_intent...")
        exit_intent_steps.recenter_mouse_pointer()
        exit_intent_steps.trigger_intent()
        self.assertTrue(exit_intent_page.find_modal().is_displayed())

    @allure.suite("Exit intent")
    @allure.title("Closing Modal window")
    @allure.description("checking modal window closes")
    def test_02_exit_intent_dismiss(self):
        base_steps.open_exit_intent()
        print("Running test_exit_intent_dismiss...")
        exit_intent_steps.recenter_mouse_pointer()
        exit_intent_steps.trigger_intent()
        exit_intent_steps.exit_intent()
        self.assertFalse(exit_intent_page.find_modal().is_displayed())
```